# HTML div isn't displaying full height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on this relatively simple site:

http://harrisonfjord.com/folio/test.html

The images being displayed are 800x600; the div that they are in **should** push the bottom of the page down (so the menu/nav arrows are lower) but for some reason this isn't happening. Instead, the images are being cut off at about 550px on the y-axis.

I'm using swipe.js (controlled by the arrows below the folio images) alongside jQuery Cycle (controlled by the nav menu at the bottom). The Swipe script may be causing problems because it relies on overflow:hidden to navigate around the page, but figuring out anything more than this is beyond me.

Any ideas on how to fix this seemingly simple issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your div does not have the correct auto-height because your div with the id `asics` has `position:absolute`. Absolute positioned elements are not respected when calculating a parent's height. Remove it or change it to `position:relative`.

```
<div class="adSlideBox" id="asics" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; opacity: 1; display: block; z-index: 7; ">
```

Comment: Also consider using a .css file instead of lots of style attributes

Comment: Those style attributes are being added by jQuery Cycle, not in the code. Considering getting rid of it because it seems to be causing a fair few problems.

Comment: Regardless, removing position:absolute fixes the problem. Now need to find a way to alter Cycle so it doesn't inject that bloody style attribute!

Answer (score 0):

The `Div` `#adSlideshow` is only about `400~px`, something else must be going on.
Can't you do `#adSlideshow { height:800px; }` ?